# lsof hangs forever centos 7

Tags: centos7, lsof

Having an issue where `lsof` hangs forever. I thought it might have been caused by the NFS mount which was recently interrupted and remounted, however, I tried unmounting the NFS mount and it's still doing it.

`dmesg` is showing a block on nvme1n1. However, that drive has been removed.

```
[47343829.954637] EXT4-fs error (device nvme1n1): __ext4_get_inode_loc:4180: inode #4980737: block 19922976: comm lsof: unable to read itable block
```

`lsof -b` shows

```
sof: avoiding stat(/files/nfsshare): -b was specified.
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() nfs4 file system /files/nfsshare
      Output information may be incomplete.
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "that drive has been removed"? Did you yank it out while the system was still running?

Comment: This is an AWS EC2 instance. The volume was removed in AWS after being unmounted in centos.